# Scriptaculous Autocompleter wont work in Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, autocomplete, scriptaculous

I am working on a project which implements an autocomplete textfield with the Scriptaculous autocompleter. In versions of Internet Explorer less than 10, the system works fine, but since version 10 and in other browsers like Firefox or Chrome, the autocompletion is defective. I have already updated the Scriptaculous to 1.9 with prototype 1.7, but nothing changed.

```
<label for="possibleClient">Verfügbare Klienten</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="possibleClient" class="fill intellisense"><div id="possibleClientUpdate" class="auto-complete"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // <![CDATA[

            function updateClientList(input,listitem) {

                var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('informal', listitem) || [];
                if(nodes.length>0) label = Element.collectTextNodes(nodes[0], listitem);
                addToList("chosenClients",input.value,label);
                input.value="";
            }

            var ac = new Ajax.Autocompleter('possibleClient','possibleClientUpdate','/data/clients.php',{paramName: 'search',minChars:1, parameters:'projektIDs=<?php echo $projektID ?>&searchnName=true', select:'selectme', afterUpdateElement: updateClientList});
            // ]]>
            </script>
```

I don't have any idea.

**[UPDATE]**

Hi tanks for all the quick answers. What do I mean with defective. I am updating an older system to get it ready for any browsers. Defective means that autocomplete doesent work. If I type something in nothing happens in newer browsers. It works in the ie 10 when your activate the compatibility mode.

The System didn`t uses a json file. The /data/clients.php returns a

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

text passage.

e.g.:

```
<ul><li><span class='informal'>Aicher Jasmin</span> (<span class='selectme'>65</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Bader Jacqueline Bernice</span> (<span class='selectme'>77</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Freisslich Claudia</span> (<span class='selectme'>78</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Goller Sascha</span> (<span class='selectme'>64</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Hebein Ilse</span> (<span class='selectme'>75</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Hohenwarter Berndt</span> (<span class='selectme'>60</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kanz Bernhard</span> (<span class='selectme'>69</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kohlmaier Angelika</span> (<span class='selectme'>68</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Konic Isabella</span> (<span class='selectme'>71</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kosche Karl-Heinz</span> (<span class='selectme'>63</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kreilitsch Jutta</span> (<span class='selectme'>70</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kribitsch Bernhard</span> (<span class='selectme'>61</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Lackner Ermelinde</span> (<span class='selectme'>79</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>M&ouml;sslacher Wolfgang</span> (<span class='selectme'>67</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>M&uuml;ller Hans</span> (<span class='selectme'>54</span>)</li></ul>
```

I also dont think that the datasource is the problem, because it works fine with older browsers.

If i start the developer console in firefox, and type something in:

I see that the procedure is called and that the script is geting the data from [07:35:47.367] POST https://myserver.at/data/clients.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 45ms]

But i don´t see the dropdown div with the Autocomplete suggestions.
Is it maybe a css Probleme ?
Here is the css file for the autocomplete:

```
div.auto-complete {
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid #888;
  margin:1px 1px 0 1px;
  padding:0px;
}
div.auto-complete ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
div.auto-complete ul li.selected { background-color: #ffb;}
div.auto-complete ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:2px;
  height:22px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you did wrong but I think that it's not the browser http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/scriptaculous-autocomplete.html works fine in Firefox for me.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "defective" means. Does it not work at all, or works in unexpected ways? One thing you could try is open up Chrome's Web Developer Toolbar (press F12) and see if there are any error messages in the console tab. You can do the same in IE10 (press F12), and Firefox (I'm not sure about the hotkey, right click anywhere on the page and click Inspect element...).

Comment: What does `/data/clients.php` return? and under what Content-Type? Also, try Prototype 1.7.1

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you check if the dropdown has content? And see in the console if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind why it would work in older browsers but not newer is that your JSON is invalid:

```
var b = eval("[{nooo:'json0'},{nooo:'json1'}]"); //works
var b = JSON.parse("[{nooo:'json0'},{nooo:'json1'}]")// doesn't
              // because the string isn't valid json
var b = JSON.parse('[{"nooo":"json0"},{"nooo":"json1"}]');//works, valid JSON string
```

To solve this you should have your PHP return valid JSON.

In FireFox with Firebug pligin installed could you right click the text box and choose "Inspect element with firebug" If the firebug window is docked you should see the element and below the elements are the "dropdown" results.

When you type something and the xhr request finishes then the result should have an UL element see image below when I use it on http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/scriptaculous-autocomplete.html

Does the URL I mentioned above work (it does for me with Firefox but uses 1.7)?

[image: Empty dropdown, UL contains no elements and display of div is set to none]

The following shows results:

[image: Showing dropdown, UL has children and display is not set to none]

Answer (score 0):

Hi tanks for all the quick answers. What do I mean with defective. I am updating an older system to get it ready for any browsers. Defective means that autocomplete doesent work. If I type something in nothing happens in newer browsers. It works in the ie 10 when your activate the compatibility mode.

The System didn`t uses a json file. The /data/clients.php returns a

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

text passage.

e.g.:

```
<ul><li><span class='informal'>Aicher Jasmin</span> (<span class='selectme'>65</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Bader Jacqueline Bernice</span> (<span class='selectme'>77</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Freisslich Claudia</span> (<span class='selectme'>78</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Goller Sascha</span> (<span class='selectme'>64</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Hebein Ilse</span> (<span class='selectme'>75</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Hohenwarter Berndt</span> (<span class='selectme'>60</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kanz Bernhard</span> (<span class='selectme'>69</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kohlmaier Angelika</span> (<span class='selectme'>68</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Konic Isabella</span> (<span class='selectme'>71</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kosche Karl-Heinz</span> (<span class='selectme'>63</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kreilitsch Jutta</span> (<span class='selectme'>70</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Kribitsch Bernhard</span> (<span class='selectme'>61</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>Lackner Ermelinde</span> (<span class='selectme'>79</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>M&ouml;sslacher Wolfgang</span> (<span class='selectme'>67</span>)</li><li><span class='informal'>M&uuml;ller Hans</span> (<span class='selectme'>54</span>)</li></ul>
```

I also dont think that the datasource is the problem, because it works fine with older browsers.

If i start the developer console in firefox, and type something in:

I see that the procedure is called and that the script is geting the data from [07:35:47.367] POST https://myserver.at/data/clients.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 45ms]

But i don´t see the dropdown div with the Autocomplete suggestions.
Is it maybe a css Probleme ?
Here is the css file for the autocomplete:

```
div.auto-complete {
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid #888;
  margin:1px 1px 0 1px;
  padding:0px;
}
div.auto-complete ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
div.auto-complete ul li.selected { background-color: #ffb;}
div.auto-complete ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:2px;
  height:22px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes everything works like you said, and also the sample link. But when i debugg the element the div css props are display:none and they dont change. He adds the  elements but dont shows them.

```
    <div id="possibleClientUpdate" style="display: none;">
<ul>...
</div>
```

How do i resolve this problem ?